# Sort or Filter Column, display in ranges

Tags: google-sheets

I have a log to track my running distance/times/etc. I am trying to come up with a way to display my top 10 or so times (pace/mile) at various distances (0-2.9, 3-4.9, 5-6.9, etc). I've tried to use "Sort" and I'm able to sort by distance, but I want to be able to only select the distances within those groups, then sort based on pace. Ideally, it would display Date / Distance / Pace.

I'm not quite sure what terms I'm supposed to be looking for, so it makes it hard to find.

Here's a link to my sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1d0aOsaarKaoSJNupzyk62oDh_o1yWosoi8TldCcKs0Y/edit?usp=sharing

Basically, in the "Tests" sheet, I want to display "Best Pace 3-5 Miles" and have it sort my top 10(or whatever) runs using the "Mileage" sheet column C for distance, Column F for pace, and Column B for date.

Thanks!

Comment: The title is my bad. The tutorial/posts/etc are in reference to StackOverflow posts. I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be searching for.

Comment: Put this expression somewhere into your tests sheet. `=filter(Mileage!A10:E, (Mileage!C10:C >= 3) * (Mileage!C10:C <= 5))`

Comment: Added it. This is definitely the right direction! I'll need to filter out any pace values that are 0, and then sort by time... I MIGHT be able to figure that out. We'll see!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this expression.

`=sort(filter(Mileage!A10:E, (Mileage!C10:C >= 3) * (Mileage!C10:C <= 5) * (Mileage!E10:E <> 0)), 5, false)`

Here is the documentation for filter 
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en

and for sort https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150?hl=en

`(Mileage!C10:C >= 3) * (Mileage!C10:C <= 5) * (Mileage!E10:E <> 0)` means the value in column C must be >= 3 and <= 5 and the value in E must be different from 0.
sort(range, 5, false) means: sort the 5th column in the given range in descending order.

Comment: Thank you! I've been able to handle the simplistic sorts/filters, but once things start getting nestled, I get thrown for a loop.